# I am trying to create an array with an already specificed maximum size using a class but the array does not seem to be created

Tags: c++, arrays, class, header-files

I am trying to create an array in my UnsortedList class. I specified to create an array in the header file, and I also specified the MAX_SIZE, which is equal to 10. However, whenever I create my object of the class, the default constructor does not create that array with the MAX_SIZE. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I also get an error saying "stack around the variable 'myList' was corrupted". Also, just as a side note, can I initialize the array values when the default constructor is called, instead of creating a function to do it?

"UnsortedList.h" header file:

```
#pragma once

class UnsortedList {
public:
    UnsortedList();
    bool IsFull(); //Determines whether the list is full or not (returns T or F)
    int GetLength(); //Gets the length of the list
    void SetListValues();
private:
    int length;
    const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
    int numbers[];
};
```

"UnsortedList.cpp" file:

```
#pragma once
#include "UnsortedList.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

UnsortedList::UnsortedList() {
    length = 0; //sets length to 0
    numbers[MAX_ITEMS]; //sets array maximum size to MAX_ITEMS (10 as indicated in UnsortedList.h)
}

bool UnsortedList::IsFull() {
    return (length == MAX_ITEMS);
}

int UnsortedList::GetLength() {
    return length;
}

void UnsortedList::SetListValues() {
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("values.txt");

    int x = 0;
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> numbers[x];
        x++;
    }
}
```

"main.cpp" file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "UnsortedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    UnsortedList myList;
    myList.SetListValues();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `numbers[MAX_ITEMS]; ` does not create or resize the array.

Comment: `numbers[MAX_ITEMS];` doesn't do what you think it does. At best, nothing. At worst, segmentation fault. And did you hear about `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: `while (!inFile.eof()) {` avoid this pattern because of this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: You want [`std::array<int,MAX_ITEMS>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in c++

Comment: Also `while (!inFile.eof())` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: @ypnos no, I haven't heard of either of those. Should I be using them?

Comment: @AG77 _" Should I be using them?"_ Definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use `std::array` or `std::vector`, but if you must use C arrays, then your definition in the header needs correcting:

```
class UnsortedList {
// ...
    const static int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
    int numbers[MAX_ITEMS];
};
```

You can remove the corresponding line in the constructor. The file reading method also needs correcting:

```
void UnsortedList::SetListValues() {
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("values.txt");

    int x = 0;
    int read_value;

    // x < MAX_ITEMS to avoid out of bounds access
    while (x != MAX_ITEMS && inFile >> read_value) 
    {
        numbers[x++] = read_value;

        length++; // I assume you also want to increment the length at this point?
    }
}
```

---

Edit: As noted by @πάνταῥεῖ, there is no good reason to use C style arrays when the standard provides `std::array`. Not much changes, it is declared as:

```
std::array<int, MAX_ITEMS> numbers;
```

You can use `operator[]` as with the C array. This is preferable as it provides a richer API and can be used like other C++ containers, i.e. with STL algorithms.

Comment: In the header defintion, I tried doing ```int numbers[MAX_ITEMS];``` but get an error saying "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Comment: @AG77 I forgot the static keyword before the size member!

Comment: @Mansoor _"but if you must use C arrays"_ There's no reason. If you need to interact with plain c APIs there's [`std::array::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) at hand. Would be a great improvement for your answer to mention that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ artificially imposed requirement, like an academic exercise? I agree with your point. The answer would look similar with `std::array`.

Comment: @Mansoor _"artificially imposed requirement like an academic exercise?"_ Well, in good courses they should teach how to write less error prone and production ready code. But teachers (especially the older ones) are lazy, and slacking to update their course matierials. - Just my 2¢